# Validation error show on different layout in cakephp 2.0?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I have admin_form.ctp file . When i submit it with blank data then cake validation working properly but the problem is that the layout of the form changs and url is same.I mean all validation and url of page are correct but the layout of page changed .

If any body have any suggestion please let me know as soon as possible.
Thanks.

admin_form.ctp

```
<?php echo $this->Form->create('Page');
            echo $this->Form->input('id');
        ?>
        <div>
        <?php echo $this->Form->input('title',array('onblur' => "MetaTitle()",'class'=>'sprited')); ?>
        </div>
        <div>
        <?php echo $this->Form->input('alias',array('class'=>'sprited')); ?>
        </div>
        <div>
        <?php echo $this->Form->input('description',array('type' => 'textarea' , 'class' => 'ckeditor sprited')); ?>
        </div>
        <div>
        <?php echo $this->Form->input('meta_title',array('class'=>'sprited')); ?>
        </div>
        <div>
        <?php echo $this->Form->input('meta_keyword',array('class'=>'sprited')); ?>
        </div>
        <div>
        <?php echo $this->Form->input('meta_description',array('class'=>'sprited')); ?>
        </div>
         <div class="status">
        <?php echo $this->Form->input('status',array('class'=>'sprited')); ?>
        </div>
        <div class="clear"></div>
        <div id="actions">
        <input type="submit" class="save"  value="Save" />
        <?php
         echo $this->Html->link(__('Cancel'), array(
                'action' => 'index',
        ), array(
                'class' => 'cancel',
        ));
        ?>
```

Controller code :-

```
 public function admin_add() {
        $this->layout = 'admin';
        $this->set('title_for_layout', __('Add new page', true));
        if (!empty($this->request->data)) {
            $this->Page->create();
            $this->request->data['Page']['user_id'] = $this->Auth->User('id');
            if($this->data['Page']['alias']==""){
        $this->request->data['Page']['alias']=$this->data['Page']['title'];
            }
            $this->request->data['Page']['alias'] = $this->title_to_alias(trim($this->data['Page']['alias']));
            if ($this->Page->save($this->request->data)) { 
                $this->Session->setFlash(__('The page has been saved.'), 'default', array('class' => 'success'));
                $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
            } else {
                $this->Session->setFlash(__('The page could not be saved. Please, try again.'), 'default', array('class' => 'error'));
            }
        }
        $this->render('admin_form');
    }
```

Comment: 1. Is that form is submitting to admin side action ? otherwise Please post your code.. so that we can track.

Comment: Yes, The form is submitting to admin side action.

Comment: can u please post ur ctp code and controller code ??

Answer (score 0):

If you want to customize the layout of the validation message, you can create a personal css file and overwrite the `error-message` class properties...